# SIM toolkit application - Javacard development kit

Tags: javacard, sim-toolkit

I'm trying to develop a STK application but I don't know where to get the development kit. Right now for Javacard I'm getting the one from Oracle's website, but it doesn't have the sim.toolkit package.

I don't want to buy it from Gemalto, etc. Is there any "free" implementation?

I have found the [ETSI - 3GPP](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/0319.htm) a zip file with some code and libraries, but I don't know if this would be enough. Do I generate the cap/jar file from the code there?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The files from 3GPP should be enough to complement the Javacard libraries that you've downloaded from Oracle.

Just as you need to know the Javacard version of your card, you need to know also what version of SIM API the card support. Check it againsts the 3GPP TS 03.19 that you've mentioned, or you may also check for [3GPP TS 43.019](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/43019.htm). Download the correct version.

Here is some steps I used to generate SIM API library:

1. Download related SIM API archieve, for example [3GPP 43.019 v5.6.0](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/43_series/43.019/43019-560.zip)
2. Extract the `43019-560.zip` file
3. Extract `Annex_A_java.zip` under it
4. Open the extracted `Annex_A_java` directory
5. Zip the `sim` folder
6. Rename the `sim.zip` extension to `sim_v5.6.0.jar`

Besides the JAR file, you also need to copy the export files (required when generating CAP file).

1. Extract `Annex_B_Export_Files.zip`
2. Open `Annex_B_Export_Files` directory
3. Copy the `sim` directory into your collection of export files directory.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How we can convert SIM API contained packages to CAP files? As far as I know, _JCDK Converter_ tool is able to convert pure Java Card APIs to CAP files only and it is not useful for SIM APIs, right?

Comment: We don't need to convert API to CAP file. What we need to do is to convert class files to CAP file. JCDK is able to convert any APIs. Just make sure that you put the JAR and the EXPort files of the API.

Comment: I must add the _JAR_ files to my project. but what about the _Exp_ files? where I must put them? (I know that I must put the in the directory of other export files, but where are those?)

Comment: You can add it under java_card_kit-2_2_2\api_export_files, along with com, java, javacard, and javacardx directory.